# Unexpected behaviour on popup warning when adding comments

Tags: bug, comment-replies

I was adding a comment to a question in Russian.SE and included two `@` references to notify two different users.  When I attempted to submit the comment, I got a pop-up indicating that only one additional user can be notified with `@` reference.

Without explicitly closing the popup, I changed the text of the comment removing one of the `@` signs and then hit "enter" key to submit the comment.  The comment was added and the popup disappeared.

Then I needed to add another comment to the same post, so I pressed "add comment" link and got a blank field to add the comment - with the same red popup still visible.  In fact, it kept showing up until I explicitly closed it or navigated to another page.  While it's not really a big deal, it's just strange to see a warning popup about the content of a comment when I haven't even started entering the comment.

**EDIT:** I'm working on a Linux Ubuntu 12.04 machine and this happens on Firefox 20, Chrome 26 and Chromium 25.

**EDIT 2:** Thanks to Sha Wiz Dow Ard, here's [a short video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=csCMQWiT_Cw) demonstrating the bug.

Comment: When you report this type of thing, it's always a good idea to add your browser (+version) and OS. Quite a few of these types of glitches end up depending on your specific browser.

Comment: @Mat sorry, my mistake; I added os/browser info.

Comment: Yep, can reproduce with Chrome (latest version) so don't think this one is browser specific.

Comment: [Short vid showing this bug in action](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=csCMQWiT_Cw), feel free to add this to your post as well. :)